# Why in Android ContentProvider I can't use context like 'this'instead of getContext()

Tags: android

```
    public boolean onCreate() {
      Context context = getContext();
      mDbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
      return true;
   }

    public boolean onCreate() {
      mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);        // why this not work?
      return true;
   }
```

Why I can't use context like 'this' instead of getContext()

Comment: `ContentProvider` does not extend from `Context`. [It directly extends from `Object`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use 'this' inside an Activity or an Application, because they can behave as Context.

If your class doesn't extend from Context or Activity or Application, you can't use 'this' because the 'DbHelper' constructor needs a context.

Comment: You are awesome!